# Error running local camel context

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb

I am trying to execute the examples in Camel in action.

When I try to execute the "Spring DSL->Run As Local Camel Context" I am getting below error in JBoss Developer IDE:

> Source locator does not exist: org.fusesource.ide.server.karaf.core.server.sourceLocator

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of the build system of the project, but if it is Maven you may add following plugin to the `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <!--
          the spring context file must be separate from the OSGi bundle, so we provide one here 
        -->
        <fileApplicationContextUri>
            src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml
        </fileApplicationContextUri>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

where you can put the path to the `camel-context.xml`, and then you can run

```
mvn camel:run
```

to test the routes.

Hope I've helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I had updated the plugin for fuse integration in Jboss IDE and it is working fine now.
Thanks a lot for your response.